# Error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '->' token on line 24

Tags: c

```
/*Add a new node to the top of the list*/
        firstlist  *insert_top(char entry->name, char entry->address, int entry->phone, firstlist*head)
        {


            firstlist *new_node;
            new_node=(firstlist*)malloc(sizeof(firstlist));
            new_node->name=entry->name;
            new_node->address=entry->address;
            new_node->phone=entry->phone;
            new_node->next=head;
            head=new_node;
            return head;

        }
```

> I have this error on line 24:
>   Error] expected ';', ',' or ')' before '->' token
>
> https://pastebin.com/LsNwAgQE

Hope you guys help.

Comment: You can't have constructs such as `char entry->name` in your parameters list. What these even supposed to mean?

Comment: I am beginning  my programming in C, hope you guys help me. Thanks

Comment: You haven't defined anything called `entry`, and even if you had, a parameter name has to be a single identifier. The expression `entry->name` implies that `entry` would be a pointer to a structure, and perhaps your function should have a parameter of that pointer type rather than separate `name`, `address`, and `phone` parameters.

Comment: How to define an entry? And what do you mean by a parameter of a pointer type?

Comment: Hope you guys help

Comment: It depends how you intend to call `insert_top`, your code doesn't show that and therefore it's somewhat hard to guess what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `entry->name` from the `insert_top` function definition.

There are 2 ways to pass entry. As a struct:

```
firstlist  *insert_top(firstlist *entry, firstlist*head)
```

then you can use the `entry` members such as `entry->name`

and calling it later:

```
head=insert_top(entry, head);
```

The other option is using separate values:

```
firstlist  *insert_top(char name, char address, int phone, firstlist *head)
```

At that point, you can't use `entry->name` since your function doesn't know who entry is, just use `name`

calling `insert_top` in this option is the same as what you did:

```
head=insert_top(entry->name, entry->address, entry->phone, head);
```

Comment: It now said that the firstlist has no member name entry.